# hiding rows based on a cell for multiple worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, submodule

I have a folder with multiple worksheets each sheet is for a separate date. I want to hide rows based on the cell information in F5. I have managed to get this working for one sheet but not multiple.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("f5").Value = "Flat" Then
     Rows("29:62").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("F5").Value <> "Flat" Then
    Rows("29:62").EntireRow.Hidden = False

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to loop through  the worksheets. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25953916/excel-vba-looping-through-multiple-worksheets) may be of use

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

*You can use this VBA(Macro) code to hide Rows from `29 to 62` in all available Sheets in the 
Workbook.*

```
Sub HideRows()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each sht In Worksheets
    beginRow = 29
    endRow = 62

    For Rowcnt = beginRow To endRow

        If Sheets("sheet1").Range("F5").Value = "Flat" Then

            sht.Rows(Rowcnt).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            sht.Rows(Rowcnt).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If

    Next Rowcnt
Next sht

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Note,** instead of Rows `29:62`, I've used `60:65` and Criteria is `Y` in `A55`. *You may alter them.*

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

**How it works:**

- *Copy & Paste* this code as *Standard Module* along with *Sheet1*.
- *Sheet Name `Sheet1`,* *Criteria Cell reference `(F5)`,Value `Flat`* & *Row Dimensions `29:62`* are editable.

---

**Method 2:**

*This Code can be used to hide Rows `29:62` in Certain Sheets only.*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Intersect(Target, Range("F5:F5")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Address = ("$F$5") And Target.Value = "Flat" Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Rows("29:62").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Target.Address = ("$F$5") And Target.Value <> "Flat" Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Rows("29:62").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ElseIf Target.Address = ("$F$5") And Target.Value = "Flat" Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").Rows("29:62").EntireRow.Hidden = Ture
    ElseIf Target.Address = ("$F$5") And Target.Value <> "Flat" Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").Rows("29:62").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

- *This Code may comprise Sheets of your choice to hide Rows.*

Comment: Thank you but none of these are working

Comment: @Gazzaw,, both code are functional and been tested also,, just write me if you are receiving any error?

Comment: @Gazzaw, check the post,, now I've included Screen Shots !